# How can I set a key value at the impression level in Google AdManager/DFP?

Tags: google-dfp, google-ad-manager

I'm working on a script that will refresh ads after 30 seconds of engaged on screen time. What I'd like to do is track in AdManager how these refreshed ads perform and how much they are adding to my bottom line.

I'd like to set up a key value like "reloaded" that has a true of false value indicating whether that impression was an initial load of the ad unit or a refreshed load after 30 seconds of engaged time.

I can't seem to figure out how to do this. It looks like you only have the option of setting key values at the page or ad unit level, not the impression. Anyone know how to achieve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You are able to add a key and an attached value to a specific slot before refreshing it. Then, you can use it after the slot refreshed. Below is the demonstration :

## Step 1 : Page setup

```
<script async='async' src='https://www.googletagservices.com/tag/js/gpt.js'></script>
<script>
  var googletag = googletag || {};
  googletag.cmd = googletag.cmd || [];
</script>

<script>
  var slots = {}
    googletag.cmd.push(function() {

  slots['banner'] = googletag.defineSlot('/adpath', [[728, 90]], 'banner').addService(googletag.pubads()).setTargeting('key1', 'value1');

  googletag.pubads().enableSingleRequest();
  googletag.pubads().setCentering(true);
  googletag.pubads().collapseEmptyDivs(true);
  googletag.enableServices();

  });
</script>

<div id='banner'>
  <script>
    googletag.cmd.push(function() {
      googletag.display('banner'); 
    });
  </script>
</div>
```

## Step 2 : Check the attached key to the slot

```
//in your console
slots['banner'].getTargetingKeys()
//should log >> Array [ "key1" ]
```

## Step 3 : add a new key in js

```
<script>
slots['banner'].setTargeting('reloaded','true')
</script>
```

## Step 4 : reload the slot

```
<script>
googletag.pubads().refresh(slots[0])
</script>
```

## Step 5 : Check the attached key to the slot

```
//in your console
slots['banner'].getTargetingKeys()
//should log >> Array [ "key1", "reloaded" ]
```

With this set up, you are able to identify / target the "reloaded = true" inventory within your Google Ad Manager interface.

Related documentation :

> [GPT setTargeting](https://developers.google.com/doubleclick-gpt/reference#googletag.PubAdsService_setTargeting)
>   [GPT getTargetingKeys](https://developers.google.com/doubleclick-gpt/reference#googletag.PubAdsService_getTargetingKeys)
>   [GPT refresh](https://developers.google.com/doubleclick-gpt/reference#googletag.PubAdsService_refresh)

Hope this helps.